# Change default font in rich text field

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, rich-text

Using Sharepoint 2010 Foundation I got a list with a field that is Multiple lines of text/Enhanced rich text. I want to change the default font and font-size for this field (and other rich text fields).

I've googled it but none of the solutions works. :-/

Ivar

Answer (score 1):

You would need to overwrite the core.css files for your SharePoint farm, which I wouldn't recommend. An alternative is to let the users type in whatever they want, and customize how it is displayed using CSS.